# How to get the css properties before adding to dom?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a code like this, this is an example code,

```
<style>
    .divStyle
    {
        border: 2px solid gray;
    }
</style>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var div = $("<div class='divStyle'></div>");
        var border = div.css("border");
    });
</script>
```

the border returns empty string. how to get the border value ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant get it done without inserting it to the `DOM` but here is a trick I can think of and it's that insert it into dom as hidden, get the css property and remove it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var div = $("<div class='divStyle'></div>").css('display','none').appendTo('body');
    var border = div.css('border');
    div.remove();
    alert(border);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/izidoj/1/edit).

Comment: What about this. it has a parent, the parent is not add to dom ?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying but I think you know what it has because you are creating it in your example, anyways, it's an idea only.

Comment: thanks i found this, just take a clone of that div and append that to body.

Answer (score 1):

You could insert a hidden input, with the class, get the css properties and the use them.

```
<input id="getPadding" class="inp" type="text" style="display:none" />
```

Then after the element is appended You can just get the elements parent width and then set the input to that width minus the amount of padding.. Like so

```
 $('td input').width($(this).parent().width() - [$('#getPadding').css('padding-left') + $('#getPadding').css('padding-right')])
```

Alternatively there is a css only solution but it does not work in IE7 and below

```
 $('td input').width($(this).parent().width() - [$('#getPadding').css('padding-left') + $('#getPadding').css('padding-right')])
Alternatively there is a css only solution but it does not work in IE7 and below

td input {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0px;
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Render your element invisible. Something like this:

```
 var div = $("<div class='divStyle'></div>"); // Create
     $(body).append(div);  // Render
     $(div).hide();  // Hide immediately
 var border = $(div).css("border");  // Get value
    $(div).remove();   // Destroy
```